# Partial search/find in CouchDB

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb

This may actually be a stupid question but I don't understand how the querying process works in CouchDB. I come from a MongoDB background, and can't really apply what I know.

Let's say I have a database of recipes of the form:

```
{
  "_id": "335ddc061465ec83b50b4f8d4100058d",
  "_rev": "2-b43fde3b553c08e8dd6ce19e397ec244",
  "title": "Recipe title",
  "ingredients": [
    "ingredient 1",
    "ingredient 2"
  ],
  "procedure": "What you need to do to cook the recipe",
  "pictures": [
    "picture_url_1",
    "picture_url_2"
  ],
  "videos": [
    "video_url_1",
    "video_url_2"
  ],
  "date": "some_date"
}
```

I'd like to write a query such as given one or more terms it finds a list of possible result for the search (i.e., I could look for something like "recipe with a similar title ingredient 1"). Ideally as first step I would split the query and look for the terms in the procedure, title, and ingredients in each document. I found [this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#find-selectors) and looking under the condition operators but I don't seem to find something similar to the `.find` function in mongo with parameters like `{ $text: { $search: "similar title ingredient 1" } }`. I'd like to learn the CouchDB way to perform such a logical OR query on a list of documents.

I'm using Node.js + Express and using node-couch to interact with the DB. As for why I have picked CouchDB with respect to Mongo which I already know, I just wanted to learn how to use Couch :). Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches that may work for you.

1. Look at [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene). This allows you to use lucene against data from CouchDB.
2. Write a giant [view](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html) that emits tokens for everything and query against that.

The first option is probably best if installing it is an option for you, and you don't need this to work in PouchDB as well. The second is a lot more basic, but will work in both situations and doesn't require any third-party tools.

Comment: I switched back to Mongo, but I'll keep your solution in mind if I decide to go back to CouchDB!